# Vertically center text inside a div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to vertically center some text inside a div. Sounds easy but I can't get it. Here's the code, sorry for the bad formatting and practices, it's something whipped up fast and dirty:

```html
<div id="container" style="text-align:center ;border: 5px solid blue; display:flex; flex-direction:row ; justify-content:center; height:100px">
  <div id="first" style=" min-height:100px; min-width:200px; background-color:green">
    <div style="vertical-align:middle">
      first box
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="second" style=" min-height:100px; min-width:200px;  background-color:yellow">
    <div style="vertical-align:middle">
      second box
    </div>
  </div>
  <svg version="1.1" id="SVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" height="100%" width: "auto">
     <!--snipped away svg code-->

 </svg>
  <div id="third" style="min-height:100px; min-width:200px; background-color:red">
    <div style="">
      third box
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="fourth" style="min-height:100px; min-width:200px; background-color:cyan; vertical-align:middle ">
    <p>
      fourth box
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

As you can see, there's four boxes around a central svg image. Horizontally centering the elements inside the "container" div was easy, vertically centering the text inside each of those elements is not. Not at all.

I've tried various solutions, none of which worked like intended (the text just goes up to the top of the box). Am I missing something obvious or am I trying to do something impossible?

I'm looking for a flexible solution, something that can work without knowing the exact height in pixels of the boxes nor the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using flexbox, you don't need to use `vertical-align`.

Here are two things to consider:

1. When you create a flex container only the child elements become flex items. Any descendant elements beyond the children are *not* flex items and flex properties don't apply to them.

   Your `div` boxes wrapping your text are not flex items. They are children of flex items (`#first`, `#second`, etc.) and flex properties don't apply.
2. If you want to apply flex properties to the children of flex items, you need to make the flex item a flex container, as well.

   Try this:

   ```
   #first { 
       display: flex; 
       justify-content: center; 
       align-items: center;
   }

   #second { 
       display: flex; 
       justify-content: center; 
       align-items: center;
   }
   ```

```css
#first {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#second {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="text-align:center ;border: 5px solid blue; display:flex; flex-direction:row ; justify-content:center; height:100px">
  <div id="first" style=" min-height:100px; min-width:200px; background-color:green">
    <div style="vertical-align:middle">first box</div>
  </div>
  <div id="second" style=" min-height:100px; min-width:200px;  background-color:yellow">
    <div style="vertical-align:middle">
      second box
    </div>
  </div>
  <svg version="1.1" id="SVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" height="100%" width: "auto">
       <!--snipped away svg code-->

</svg>
  <div id="third" style="min-height:100px; min-width:200px; background-color:red">
    <div style="">
      third box
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="fourth" style="min-height:100px; min-width:200px; background-color:cyan; vertical-align:middle ">
    <p>
      fourth box
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

Re: **`vertical-align`**

The reason [`vertical-align: middle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) wasn't working for you is because this property centers within the *inline dimension*. So it actually was vertically centering the text... within its `line-height`. To get the behavior you expect, specify a `line-height` equal to the container height.

```
#third {
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

```css
#first {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#second {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#third {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="text-align:center ;border: 5px solid blue; display:flex; flex-direction:row ; justify-content:center; height:100px">
  <div id="first" style=" min-height:100px; min-width:200px; background-color:green">
    <div style="vertical-align:middle">first box</div>
  </div>
  <div id="second" style=" min-height:100px; min-width:200px;  background-color:yellow">
    <div style="vertical-align:middle">
      second box
    </div>
  </div>
  <svg version="1.1" id="SVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" height="100%" width: "auto">
       <!--snipped away svg code-->

</svg>
  <div id="third" style="min-height:100px; min-width:200px; background-color:red">
    <div style="">
      third box
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="fourth" style="min-height:100px; min-width:200px; background-color:cyan; vertical-align:middle ">
    <p>
      fourth box
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: So it _was_ the obvious thing after all. After seeing "text-align: center" in the container affect the text in the boxes I thought the display properties trickled down in the same way...
Thank you very much, for the vertical-align explanation too

Answer (score 1):

This code will center all the text:

```
#container div div, #container div p {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0;
}
```

Expand this live demo to see it in action:

```css
#container {
    text-align:center;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:center;
    height:100px;
}
#first {
    min-height:100px;
    min-width:200px;
    background-color:green;
}
#second {
    min-height:100px;
    min-width:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#third {
    min-height:100px;
    min-width:200px;
    background-color:red;
}
#fourth {
    min-height:100px;
    min-width:200px;
    background-color:cyan;
}
#container div div, #container div p {
    position: relative;
 top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="first">
        <div>first box</div>
    </div>
    <div id="second">
        <div>second box</div>
    </div>
    <svg version="1.1" id="SVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" height="100%" width: "auto">
        <!--snipped away svg code-->
    </svg>
    <div id="third">
        <div>third box</div>
    </div>
    <div id="fourth">
        <p>fourth box</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Normally just the first three properties are required, but your fourth element was a `<p>` element, which has top and bottom margins, so I added `margin: 0;` to cancel those out. This is the most reliable way to center elements vertically regardless of markup unless you can use flexbox.

Comment: *This is the most reliable way to center elements vertically in modern browsers...* ... c'mon my friend! In modern browsers, flexbox does well, too.

Comment: @Michael_B True, but there's worse support for flexbox & co. than there is for transform.

Comment: I guess it boils down to how we define *modern*. Browser support: [**flexbox**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) & [**transform**](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform)

Comment: @Michael_B Yes, both are more or less supported in the latest versions of each major browser, but there are way more instances of browsers not supporting/having trouble with the flexbox way than with the transform way. Hence, *most reliable*. I probably would have included a flexbox method in my answer, but you had already provided it in your answer, so I stuck with the more reliable method only.