# Center Text Vertically with Flexbox, not creating result I want

Tags: html, css

I need help with this, I'm not quite sure how to explain my problem in words, so here is a picture. [this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5yX7.png)

[this is what I want it to look like (from another website)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZOSr.png) Not style an all, just the centering style.

I want my links to be centered like this: 
HOME ABOUT SPENCER HILTBRAND SERVICES CONTACT

Heres my CSS

```
    /* Navigation */

    .navigation {
      background: #fff;
      width: 100%;
      height: 156px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     }

     .nav-item {
      text-decoration: none !important;
      font-size: 35px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      transition: 0.3s color;
      padding: 20px;
     }
```

HTML structure:

```
<!-- Header -->
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <a class="nav-item">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-item">About</a>
      <a class="brand"><i class="orange">Spencer</i> Hiltbrand</a>
      <a class="nav-item">Services</a>
      <a class="nav-item">Contact</a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Spencer - Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's helpful if we can reproduce the problem you're having. Please post your HTML and CSS. Here's some  more guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: a `margin:auto;` on `.nav-item` would do if they are direct child of `.navigation` ... too much flex disturbs flex :)

Comment: @GCyrillus Read my update, maybe it will help you understand better, your suggestion didn't work.

Comment: Okay, (repeating) we need your HTML :), so we do see the structure , is it a nav + a ? or a nav + ul + li + a ? or something else ?. structure matters, css on its own has no purpose --- image just tells what the issue looks like, not why and where it went wrong

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot about that.     <!-- Header -->
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navigation">
        <ul>
          <a class="nav-item">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item">About</a>
          <a class="brand"><i class="orange">Spencer</i> Hiltbrand</a>
          <a class="nav-item">Services</a>
          <a class="nav-item">Contact</a>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

Comment: Your HTML should be posted in the question, not as a comment. But in looking at it , a `ul` without list items (`li`) is not valid HTML. The simplest solution is to remove the `<ul>` and `</ul>`. They're not necessary. Then the `<nav>` will wrap your anchor elements and they will be vertically centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i commented, you may use  `margin:auto;` and from your HTML we can see what went wrong: this is that lonely `<ul>` tag :

```css
   /* Navigation */
   .navigation {
     background: #fff;
     width:100%;
     height: 156px;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     /* demo purpose : flex-wrap:wrap or min-width */
    min-width:1000px;
   }
   .nav-item {
     text-decoration: none !important;
     font-size: 35px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     transition: 0.3s color;
     padding: 20px;
   }
   .nav-item,
   .brand {
     margin: auto 0;
   }
   .brand {
     font-size: 50px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
   }
   .orange {
     color: orange;
   }
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navigation">
    <a class="nav-item">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-item">About</a>
    <a class="brand"><i class="orange">Spencer</i> Hiltbrand</a>
    <a class="nav-item">Services</a>
    <a class="nav-item">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the answer has already been given in another post. [Vertically centering text inside flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334732/vertically-centering-text-inside-flexbox-div?rq=2)

```
#first { 
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;
}

#second { 
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fv5j4kob/1/) given in the post.

Comment: Read my update, maybe it will help you understand better.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that much code - this is sufficient:

http://jsfiddle.net/zfg2sg9L/1/

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="x">
        first box
    </div>
    <div class="x">
        second box
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x80">
    <div class="x">
       third box
    </div>
    <div class="x">
        fourth box
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center;   
}
.x {
    margin: auto 20px;
}
```

The container gets `justify-content: center` to center the whole thing horzontally. The flex items get `margin: auto 20px;`: The `auto`  for top and bottom margin to center them vertically, the 20px left and right to create some distance between the items. That's all it really needs.